# Transform a list of md files to html in Jekyll

Tags: console-application, jekyll

I am building a console application that go out to GitHub via octokit and fetch all the matched readme.md files. Then I saved these .md files to _posts folder in my Jekyll project.

I used the `jekyll build` command to build at the `_posts` dir level. It created a `_site` folder only contains .md files but .html. What am I missing here?

Comment: your missing the code ... in this question that is.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please update your answer to explain what you expect to see versus what you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

`jekyll build` shouldn't run inside `_posts` folder, it should be executed at root level, i.e., tipically where your `_config.yml` is.

```
.
├── 404.html
├── about.md
├── _config.yml
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── index.md
└── _posts
    └── 2017-08-06-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
```

Then your generated website will be located at `/_site`.